# Looping a dataframe from the column from the same table in scala

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, hadoop

I have DataFrame in which it will contain table name with data. I need to loop the DataFrame with the table column name. Is there a better way to do it with a collect at first?

```
val tablename:Array[String] = df1.select("msgname").distinct().rdd.map(row=>row.getString(0).trim).collect

tablename.foreach{table =>
  //print(table)
  //val columns:Array[String] = df1.filter(s"msgname = '$table'").select("columns").distinct().rdd.map(row=>row.toString()).collect
  df1.filter(s"msgname = '$table'").select("record_data").write.saveAsTable(s"$table")
    //.toDF(columns:_*).show()
    //.toDF(columns:_*).show()
}
```

Comment: Any help on the performance?

Answer (score 0):

2 ideas to improve performance: cache df1 and/or fire parallel spark jobs e.g. using parallel collections, like this:

```
df1.cache()    
val tablename:Array[String] = df1.select(trim("msgname")).distinct().as[String].collect

tablename
.par // enable parallel execution
.foreach{table =>
     df1.filter(s"msgname ='$table'").select("record_data").write.saveAsTable(s"$table")
}
```

Comment: Is there any other option without collect?

Comment: @Matrix No I think not, why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Bringing all the table names to driver why cannot be use df1.select(trim("msgname")).distinct().as[String] directly in tablename for looping but is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: @Matrix because dataframes (and therefore also `saveAsTables`) can only be accessed on the driver, the dataframe is null on the executors